# CalendarView Android Help

Tags: java, android, calendar

I am trying to display a calendar in my view layout using the CalendarView and highlight/put markers on certain event dates(as per user input) which I can then click for details on that event. I don't want to redirect to a different online calendar... rather, I just need to use a built in offline one.

Comment: I have the calendar added in the xml layout, but I don't know where to go in the java file, or how to add a marker on a certain date... if you could give me some sample code or direct me to an appropriate tutorial it would be helpful...

Comment: @Kgrover did you ever find anything out about CalendarView? assuming (3.0)

Comment: No, @willmel, I decided to drop the idea, but I would definitely be willing to listen if you had any awesome tutorial! :)

Comment: I wrote a custom Calendar / Calendar Activity that I was thinking about making open source. Would that help? It definitely could use some love to make it a little more refined, so that's part of the reason I'd like to do that.

Comment: @Blaskovicz : Yes! That would be awesome! Sorry for the later response.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, after putting the CalendarView in the XML file, you need to announce it in the code when ever you might use it, for example in the MainActivity Class:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        
     setContentView(R.layout.main);

     final CalendarView calView = (CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.calView);
     // then use it. for Exapmle:
     Date tmpDate = new Date(calView.getDate());
     // and so on.....
}
```

Is thsthelpfull to you?

Comment: how would I use it, more specifically? Cannot seem to find much help on this. Could you direct me or answer? Thanks.

Comment: You have basic documentation on Android's Website.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CalendarView.html

Answer (score 1):

Its little bit tricky.You can create your own calender view by drawing a gridView on a dialoge or a gridview on a layout (according to your requirement) and render all the dates on the that grid.You need to manually handle start date logic.i.e. from which item of the grid to start showing you date.an on that grid  you can draw your marker easily.